# Failing to assign a value to an enum

Tags: c#, enums

Did you ever have a day when nothing works? Now I can't even succeed in setting the value of an enum!

I was having trouble with the `Enum.Parse` statement at the bottom, so I've written the 'if' block above it. To my surprise, this also failed.

I traced this with the debugger. The value of the string `x` is “OnDemand”. The first 'if''s "true" branch is taken, but `bitmapCacheOption` stays `BitmapCacheOption.Default`.

Ditto for the `Enum.Parse` expression below. So my question is: **What am I doing wrong in assigning value to an enum?**

```
BitmapCacheOption bitmapCacheOption;
if (x == "OnDemand") bitmapCacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;
else
{
   if (x == "OnLoad") bitmapCacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
   else
   {
      if (x == "None") bitmapCacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
      else bitmapCacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.Default;
   }
}
BitmapCacheOption bitmapCacheOption1 =
            (BitmapCacheOption)Enum.Parse(typeof(BitmapCacheOption), x, false);
Debug.Assert(bitmapCacheOption == bitmapCacheOption1);
```

**Edit**: The enum in quesion is a WPF one, [BitmapCacheOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx). The false at the end of the Enum.Parse statement just [means](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx) to ignore the case. I'm aware of better ways to write a cascading 'if' statement (including "else if" and "switch" statements), but all this is beside the issue. I've written the 'if' this way during debugging to allow me to step through with the debugger. What is important is that even with the simple if, when x equals "OnDemand" bitmapCacheOption stays BitmapCacheOption.Default!

**edit**: Notice the value of "bitmapCacheOption" in the Debugger's Locals window - it stays in "Default" even though the yellow highlight displays that the "OnDemand" swithc case wast taken!

[image: Debugger Snap:]

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with your question but have you ever heard of `switch()` ?

Comment: Maybe you need to try with a clean build ? Also there is an `else if` available too

Comment: What was the problem with Enum.Parse?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "bitmapCacheOption stays BitmapCacheOption.Default"? How you observe this? If only while debugging it might be due to threading.

Comment: @ShadowWizard using the debugger's Locals windwo

Comment: Like I said, probably due to threading issue. Can you do something like showing a message box with the value? Or something other than the debugger? Over time I learned to not trust it, even in the newest versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: FWIW, [Windows Server 2008 Server Core is not supported][1].


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try  removing the false operator -

```
BitmapCacheOption bitmapCacheOption1 =
            (BitmapCacheOption)Enum.Parse(typeof(BitmapCacheOption), x);
```

And on the way - Upload the Enum structure for us to see if there is a problem.

### edit:wow !

[image]

it looks like they have a bug - **both** index with 0.
This is why you get the default every time. because it is 0. its fine ... but when you set the value to x - it assigns him the 0 instead anothe YYY value which should be there....

Comment: I think it's [this enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: [This source code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ler7Y.png) can indeed explain how it happened. We are all humans! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing nothing wrong here...

Look at the definition of the Enum:

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies how a bitmap image takes advantage of memory caching.
public enum BitmapCacheOption
{
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a memory store for requested data only. The first request loads the
    //     image directly; subsequent requests are filled from the cache.
    OnDemand = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Caches the entire image into memory. This is the default value.
    Default = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Caches the entire image into memory at load time. All requests for image
    //     data are filled from the memory store.
    OnLoad = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Do not create a memory store. All requests for the image are filled directly
    //     by the image file.
    None = 2,
}
```

`OnDemand` and `Default` have both 0 as value ;)

So you can't rely on the string representation of 0 casted as a value of `BitmapCacheOption`.